# Setting up WinMerge as Diff tool for Visual Studio 2019 for Git

Tags: visual-studio-2019, winmerge

First what I found is that for to change diff tool used in **Team Explorer** in **VS** I don't have settings in **VS**, I need to edit **.gitconfig**?
[EDIT] Is it possible that using portable version of WinMerge caused some problem?

So step 1:

```
git config --global --edit
```

Add values:

```
[diff]
    tool = winmerge
[difftool "winmerge"]
    cmd = "'C:/PortableApps/PortableApps/WinMergePortable/WinMergePortable.exe'" -e "$LOCAL" "$REMOTE"
[difftool]
    prompt = false
```

And that really starts **WinMerge** as diff tool, but I get following error:
[image: Both paths are invalid!]

*Both paths are invalid!*, and they really are because folder: `C:\Users\andri\AppData\Local\Temp\TFSTemp`
is empty.

What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 6):

Tried several answers and finally got it working, it seams that few more arguments were required to get it working:

```
[diff]
    tool = winmerge
[difftool "winmerge"]
    cmd = "'C:/PortableApps/PortableApps/WinMergePortable/WinMergePortable.exe'" -e -u -dl "Original" -dr "Modified" \"$LOCAL\" \"$REMOTE\"
[difftool]
    prompt = false
```